# How do I give multiple users access to a single Amazon S3 account AND determine who's added a file?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have an AWS S3 account which contains 3 buckets. I need to be able to generate access codes for a new user so that they can access the buckets and add/delete files (preferably only their own, but not a deal breaker).

I have managed to get as far as granting access to new users using IAM. However, when I read the metadata of uploaded objects (in PHP using the AWS SDK) the owner comes back as the main AWS account.

I've read *pages* of documentation but can't seem to find anything relating to determining who the owner (or uploader) of the file was.

Any advice or direction massively appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If your only problem is to find the owner of Uploaded file.

You can pass the owner info as meta-data of uploaded file.
Check http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html

In php code while uploading :

```
// Instantiate the class.
$s3 = new AmazonS3();

$response = $s3->create_object(
$bucket,
$keyname2,
array(
   'fileUpload'  => $filePath,
   'acl'         => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC,
   'contentType' => 'text/plain',
   'storage'     => AmazonS3::STORAGE_REDUCED,
   'headers'     => array( // raw headers
                      'Cache-Control'    => 'max-age',
                      'Content-Encoding' => 'gzip',
                      'Content-Language' => 'en-US',
                      'Expires'       => 'Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT',
      ),
     'meta'     => array(
                     'uploadedBy' => 'user1',
     ) )
);
print_r($response);
```

Check php api for more info.

Comment: Thanks, I should have been more specific with regards how content is added to the bucket. Various users will be adding files/objects to the bucket using Panic's Transmit4 rather than a custom uploader.